# how to create a json file from db data cgi

Tags: json, api, perl, cgi

I'm trying to get some info from a database and convert that into a json file, my database connection and loop is working fine, but when I try to print the data to the screen I see a hash instead of the json data.

```
my $query = "SELECT * FROM names";
my $conneccion = $DB_CONNECTION->prepare($query);
$conneccion->execute();

my $datos = '';
my $db_data = '';

while ($db_data = $conneccion->fetchrow_hashref()) {
    my $nombre = $db_data->{nombre};
    my $titulo   = $db_data->{titulo};

    $datos = {
        nombre => $nombre,
        titulo => $titulo, 
    };
}
 
 
use JSON::MaybeXS qw(encode_json decode_json);

my $datos_json = encode_json $datos;
say $datos_json;
```

Comment: There's no way `$datos_json` contains a hash (or a reference to a hash).

Answer (score 3):

I guess you want a list of records/hashes.

So change the definition of

```
my $datos = '';
```

to

```
my $datos = [];
```

so you can collect a list. And also:

```
$datos = {
    nombre => $nombre,
    titulo => $titulo, 
};
```

to

```
push @$datos, {
    nombre => $nombre,
    titulo => $titulo, 
};
```

to get the whole data and not only the last record.